# finding clustered NaNs but leaving lonely NaNs alone

Tags: matlab, nan

I have an incomplete dataset,

[image: http://imgur.com/Tpu6Hcf]

```
N = [NaN 1 2 3 NaN 5 6 NaN NaN 7 8 10 12 20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN]'
```

I wish to identify a cluster of Nans, that is, if the subsequent number of them exceeds 2. how do i do that?

Comment: exceeds 2 or reach 2? should row 8 and 9 get detected or not?

Comment: i want this to be modular. so more than 2 for now.

Comment: What do you expect as the output? Like you said you are looking to find more than 2 NaNs consecutively, so in your example, would the output be 15 (the starting index of that ensemble of more than 2 NaNs) OR 15,19 (starting and ending indices) OR 15,16,17,18,19 (all indices)?

Comment: In one of your comments here, you are talking about putting `-1`. Why not edit your question with the changes and output you expect?

Comment: that is correct, I was looking for the moment when im not in the nan area. i considered it not so hard, therefore i didnt include it in my question which was hard enough, at least for me :) its (clusters(1)-1) : clusters(2))

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
aux = diff([0; isnan(N); 0]);
clusters = [find(aux == 1) find(aux == -1) - 1];
```

Then clusters will be a Nx2 matrix, where N is the number of NaN clusters (all of them), and each row gives you the start and end index of the cluster.

In this example, that would be:

```
clusters =

     1     1
     5     5
     8     9
    15    19
```

It means you have 4 NaN clusters, and cluster one ranges from index 1 to index 1, cluster two ranges from 5 to 5, cluster three ranges from 8 to 9 and cluster four ranges from 15 to 19.

If you want only the clusters with at least `K` NaNs, you could do it like this (for example, with K = 2):

```
K = 2;
clusters(clusters(:,2) - clusters(:,1) + 1 >= K, :)
```

That would give you this:

```
ans =

     8     9
    15    19
```

That is, clusters 8-9 and 15-19 have 2 or more NaNs.

**Explanation:**

- **Finding the clusters**

`isnan(N)` gives you a logical vector containing the NaNs as ones:

```
N --------> NaN 1  2  3 NaN 5  6 NaN NaN 7  8 10 12 20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
isnan(N) ->  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   1  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   1   1   1
```

We want to know where each sequence of ones start, so we use `diff`, which calculates each value minus the previous one, and gives us this:

```
aux = diff(isnan(N));
N ----> NaN 1  2  3 NaN 5  6 NaN NaN 7  8 10 12 20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
aux --> -1  0  0  1 -1  0  1  0  -1  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0
```

Where a `1` indicates the group start and a `-1` indicates a group end. But it misses the first group start and the last group end, because the first `1` element is absent (it doesn't have a previous on `N` because it is the first) and the last `-1` is absent too (because there is nothing after the last `1` on `N`). A common fix is to add a zero before and after the array, which gives us this:

```
aux = diff([0; isnan(N); 0]);
N ----> NaN 1  2  3 NaN 5  6 NaN NaN 7  8 10 12 20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
aux -->  1 -1  0  0  1 -1  0  1  0  -1  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0  -1
```

Notice two things:

1. If the diff at index `i` is `1`, `N(i)` is the start of the NaN block.
2. If the diff at index `i` is `-1`, **`N(i - 1)`** is the end of the NaN block.

To get the start and end, we use `find` to get the indexes where aux == 1 and aux == -1. Hence, we call `find` twice, and concatenate both calls using `[` and `]`:

```
aux = diff([0; isnan(N); 0]);
clusters = [find(aux == 1) find(aux == -1) - 1];
```

- **Filtering the clusters whick have K or more elements**

The last step is to find clusters which have K or more elements. To do that, we first take the cluster matrix and subtract the first column from the first, and add `1`, like this:

```
clusters(:,2) - clusters(:,1) + 1
ans = 
     1
     1
     2
     5
```

It means clusters 1 and 2 have 1 NaN, cluster 3 have 3 NaNs and cluster 4 have 5 NaNs. If we ask which values are greather than or equal K, we get this:

```
clusters(:,2) - clusters(:,1) + 1 >= K
ans =
     0
     0
     1
     1
```

It's a logical array. We can use that to index only the `1` (true) rows of the cluster matrix, like this:

```
clusters(clusters(:,2) - clusters(:,1) + 1 >= K, :)
ans =

     8     9
    15    19
```

It's like asking: give us only the clusters where the rows match the ones on this logical vector, and give us all columns (denoted by the `:`).

Comment: thats very very good work. many thanks. do you always place two zeros around the isnan so you can get the diff command to work? and to be honest, i didnt quite understand the purpose behind 

clusters = [find(aux == 1) find(aux == -1) - 1]

could you elaborate the thoughts behind approaching the problem?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll edit my post to add an explanation.

Comment: that would be fantastic. the same would be true for 

clusters(clusters(:,2) - clusters(:,1) + 1 > clustercount, :)

but i thought maybe id get it when i read the first explanation ;)

something else in this regard: i realize that something happens actually before the nan cluster and id very much like to create a range of the nan cluster going from the end until the position -1. how to make a quick fix on the exact beginning where the value before the nan cluster could be still varied? in this example, -1 would mean the cluster goes from 14-19 and 7-9

Comment: Done. As for you question, if I understood it right you could just take the start and end values from the cluster matrix and decrement the start value by 1.

Comment: i understand it perfectly now and i use it in my script. it works as it is supposed to work. I very much prefer it from all other solutions so far because im working actualyl with tables, and theres a bunch of extra rules which blend in well with this structure. thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modular solution:

```
% the number of NaN you consider as a cluster
num = 3;

% moving average filter
Z = filter(ones(num,1),1,isnan(N));

x = arrayfun(@(x) find(Z == num) - num + x, 1:num,'uni',0)
y = unique(cell2mat(x))
```

**(UPDATE: faster version below)**

gives for `num = 1`:

```
y =     1     5     8     9    15    16    17    18    19
```

for `num = 2`:

```
y =     8     9    15    16    17    18    19
```

for `num = 3`, `num = 4` and `num = 5`:

```
y =    15    16    17    18    19
```

and finally for `num = 6` ... and more

```
y =   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

---

**Explanation**

`isnan(N)` returns a logical array with ones at the positions of `NaN`.

`Z = filter(ones(num,1),1,isnan(N));` is a implementation for a moving average filter with a filter window of `ones(num,1) = [1 1 1]` (for `num = 3`). So the filter of size 3 glides of the array and just reaches the value `num = 3` when there are 3 `NaN` in a row.
So it basicall looks like:

```
%//  N   isnan(N)     Z

   NaN          1     1
     1          0     1
     2          0     1
     3          0     0
   NaN          1     1
     5          0     1
     6          0     1
   NaN          1     1
   NaN          1     2
     7          0     2
     8          0     1
    10          0     0
    12          0     0
    20          0     0
   NaN          1     1
   NaN          1     2
   NaN          1     3
   NaN          1     3
   NaN          1     3
```

Now it is easy to find all elements which are **3**: `find(Z == num)` - but you also need all **2** right before: `find(Z == num) - num + 2` and all **1** right before: `find(Z == num) - num + 1`. Instead of a loop arrayfun is used, which is basically the same. As result you get a matrix with a lot of indices, lot of them mulitple, but you just need the `unique` ones. I hope everything is clear now.

Actually it would be much faster to get `find` out of arrayfun, which can then even be substituted by `bsxfun` and you can get rid of `cell2mat`, which leads to the following form:

**Faster:**

```
Z = find( filter(ones(num,1),1,isnan(N)) == num ) - num;
y = unique( bsxfun(@plus, Z,1:num) );
```

or faster the obligatory fancy one-liner:

```
y = unique(bsxfun(@plus,find(filter(ones(num,1),1,isnan(N))==num)-num,1:num));
```

Comment: many thanks for your kind response, unfortunately i am very unfamiliar with functions and although it looks very neat and clean,i just dont understand half of it given my current level. commenting some of the nice functions however might convince me to copy some parts because it really seems to be much shorter that way. what is filter doing, num, whats arrayfun good for and which unique values do you want to highlight ?

Comment: I will comment it a little more later on. If you want to detect clusters with two or more `NaN` per cluster my solution is as fast as the others. But if you just want to find clusters with 3 and more `NaN` you rather should go for Rafaels Solution.

Answer (score 1):

**STRFIND Approach**

**I. Fancy One Liner:**

```
%%// Given input N
N = [NaN 1 2 3 NaN 5 6 NaN NaN 7 8 10 12 20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN]

out = [strfind(num2str(isnan([ 0 N 0]),'%1d'),'011');strfind(num2str(isnan([ 0 N 0]),'%1d'),'110')]'
```

**Output**

out =

```
 8     9
15    19
```

**II. Detailed one with explanation:**

Basically you are trying to do sliding window checks, for which there is no direct method when working with double arrays, but after converting to strings, one can use [**`strfind`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html). This trick is used here.

I would suggest following the comments used in the code and the output numbers to understand it. Please note that for this particular case a cluster means a group of two or more consecutive NaNs

**Code**

```
%%// Given input N
N = [NaN 1 2 3 NaN 5 6 NaN NaN 7 8 10 12 20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN]

%%// Set the locations where NaNs are present and then 
%%// append at the start and end with zeros
N2 = isnan([ 0 N 0])

%%// Find the start indices of  all NaN clusters
start_ind = strfind(num2str(N2,'%1d'),'011')

%%// Find the stop indices of  all NaN clusters
stop_ind = [strfind(num2str(N2,'%1d'),'110')]

%%// Put start and stop indices into a Mx2 matrix
out = [start_ind' stop_ind']
```

**Output**

```
N =
       NaN  1  2  3  NaN  5  6  NaN NaN  7  8  10  12  20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

N2 =
     0  1   0  0  0   1   0  0   1   1   0  0   0   0   0  1   1   1   1   1   0

start_ind =
     8    15

stop_ind =
     9    19

out =
     8     9
    15    19
```

Comment: ... Although, in this case you could avoid strings using `conv`: `find(conv(2*isnan([0 N 0])-1,[1 1 -1],'valid')==3)` and ``find(conv(2*isnan([0 N 0])-1,[-1 1 1],'valid')==3)``

Comment: there is something called categorical, which works for both text and numbers for me to describe a recurring text or number. i was hassling with it in the beginning because it let me do either one or the other, but now i can call batch names from one column which contain both. i think that strfind and numfind will prove problematic again in tables which is a kind of special environment only i am using in the world - at least so it seems to me ;)

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly If you are working with `Table` and let's suppose that the Table name is `A`. If the column in the table that you are working with is named `Var1`, then you can take your `N` column vector as `A.Var1` and then use any of the codes mentioned here?

Comment: Or better just use `table2array` to get the data as a double array and do the processing as mentioned here and then write back to the table? If all these suggestions still don't work, why not share with us how you are creating the `table`?

Comment: i still couldnt find the time for this, however this week i will. i will also post a bit more details to this example which will help to understand the trouble exactly.

Comment: Sure, no worries on that!

Comment: @Luis Mendo & @ Divakar
i updated another question where i describe the use of tables more in detail, and the pitfalls of working with such structures because everything has to be converted endlessly. as i know that you already know, i will post the link nevertheless, because others might not know :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195091/recognize-relevant-string-information-by-checking-the-first-characters

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly The issue here is that I don't have access to MATLAB 2014a which started `table`? So, if you could get the data into  something like matrix/cell array/structure, would be helpful.

Comment: first 6 lines of my link to you above your post. just dont turn the data into table (2013b feature)

Answer (score 0):

This uses `diff`, as [Rafael Monteiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23035941/2586922), but seems to be simpler:

```
ind = diff([0; isnan(N(:))]);
result = find(ind(1:end-1)==1 & ind(2:end)==0);
```

In your example, this gives `[8 15]`.

*How it works*: `ind` takes the values:

- `1` where a run of (one or more) `NaN` values starts;
- `0` where there is no change between `NaN` and numeric with respect to the previous value;
- `-1` where a run of (one o more) numeric values starts.

The second line selects the positions at which a run of `NaN` starts and such that the next position is also `NaN`. Thus it gives the start of each run of more than one `NaN`, as desired.

Comment: the disadvantage which you cannot know is that im using tables and if you ever tried to diff there you would be surprised its not possible. therefore, i cant use diff for my purpose (i can, but not as easily).